# Average of numbers program outputting incorrect result

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Am trying to write simple program to find average of 3 int values, but it always seems to get the average wrong

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IntegerAverage {

public static void main(String[] args) 

{
   
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    // Ask user
    System.out.println("Input 1st number");
    num1 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input 2nd number");
    num2 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input 3rd number");
    num3 = in.nextInt();

    // Print answer
    System.out.println("The average is:"+ ((num1 + num1 + num3)/3));
}
}
```

Help is greatly appreciate

Comment: Shouldn't it be `(num1+num2+num3)/3`? You have `num1` twice.

Comment: Integer division?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's supposed to be:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class IntegerAverage {

public static void main(String[] args) 

{
   
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    // Ask user
    System.out.println("Input 1st number");
    num1 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input 2nd number");
    num2 = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Input 3rd number");
    num3 = in.nextInt();

    // Print answer
    System.out.println("The average is:"+ ((num1 + num2 + num3)/3));
}
}
```

You accidentally added num1 twice, and forgot num2.

Comment: It says i can accept in 9 minutes, am very sory will do it as soon as i can

Comment: Glad to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

Besides having `num1` twice and missing `num2`, as already mentioned above, you will always get integer-results only, e.g. for `num1 = 1`, `num2 = 2` and `num3 = 2` your code will plot `1` as result instead of `1.667`. You might enforce double-results in your output by writing

`System.out.println("The average is:"+ ((num1 + num2 + num3) / 3.0));`